# Azure Ad connection to b2c without shadowing

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We use azure b2c for a spa application.

We have allowed internal user (via azure ad) to connect to the app, that work fine but it's seem to create shadow account.

Is there a way to avoid shaddow account

Answer (score 0):

The shadow accounts are required if you're writing any extension data to the B2C object. If your application can rely solely on claims passed from the federated AAD then you should be able to remove the step in the user journey that references writeUsingAlternativeSecurityId.

Comment: ok and where i need to do that? in the identity providers of azure b2c?

Comment: I don't think it can be done with the built in user flows. You would need to create a custom policy.